# Setting and retrieving localstorage

Tags: javascript

I need to set a product id to local storage if someone accepts an offer, and then retrieve that content if they later revisit the page. If the stored id matched the current offer product id, the div containing the offer is to be hidden so they can't take advantage of it again.

The code I have to close the offer box and set the id to localstorage when they click the accept button is:

```
<script>
    var accepted = function() {

        var mydiv = document.getElementById('timed-container');

        if (mydiv.style.display === 'block' || mydiv.style.display === '')

            mydiv.style.display = 'none';
            var timedpid=<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['time_limited_pid']); ?>; 
            localStorage.setItem('timedpid', timedpid);
        }
    }
</script>
```

And then this code to check localstorage against the current offer id on page load

```
<script>
    if(localStorage.getItem('timedpid')) {

        var storedpid = localStorage.getItem('timedpid')
        var currentpid=<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['time_limited_pid']); ?>;
        if (currentpid === storepid) {

            var mydiv = document.getElementById('timed-container');
            mydiv.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
</script>
```

The current product id is stored in $_SESSION['time_limited_pid'], so in this test it is 2092.

The offer window is closing when the accept is clicked, but it is showing again if I reload the page, so either not setting localstorage, or not running the correct comparison on reload.

I'm looking for some help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Not sure if this is a mistake, but `localStorage.setItem` uses `timedpid` and `localStorage.getItem` uses `timepid`.

Comment: why you are using json_encode ?

Comment: @anshu Because that's what you're supposed to do? Duh!

Comment: In fact it's almost a shame that OP knew to use `json_encode` to safely and securely pass PHP variables into a JS environment, but tripped up on a simple `=` vs. `==` issue...

Comment: I fixed the = vs. === issue, and corrected the timepid and timedpid issue, but it still isn't working.
Those two were both stupid mistakes and Ireally should be more careful to check my code!

Comment: at the part of json_encode will make it as "object" in javascript and object comparison in js is different thing :)

Comment: @anshu No, it will make as JSON-encoded string which, when output directly into a JS code, will result in it being defined as whatever it was. For instance a string will come out as a properly quoted and escaped string.

Comment: @StevePrice You don't appear to be defining the `timedpid` variable in your first block of code.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol it is defined by var timedpid=<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['time_limited_pid']); ?>; 
Or have I done that incorrectly?

Comment: Console log in firefox shows 2092 being returned, so something else is amiss here. Will investigate further.

Comment: @StevePrice My mistake, I missed it XD Derp.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the [assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Assignment) (`=`) operator instead of [comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) for `equality` (`==`) or strict equality (`===`)

```
if (currentpid = storepid)  // <-- here you are asigning storepid to currentpid
```

Use:

```
if(currentpid === storepid) // <-- here you are comparing them
```

**NOTE**:

You are also using different strings for setting and getting an item:

```
localStorage.setItem('timedpid', timedpid); // <-- here its timedpid
// ...
localStorage.getItem('timepid');            // <-- here its timepid
```

Comment: Your `if` statement in the second script is still using `timepid` instead of `timedpid`...

Comment: Spotted that one, and no, it doesn't work even after changing it. I've replaced the json_encode with actual values to confirm it wasn't related and it made no difference

Comment: Make a  jsfiddle or something similar with the essential code and I'll take a look. Can't find any other problem with your current code.

Comment: I made a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/6xmyrbLz/2/
I had to change the format of the hide function as it didn't seem to be working on the fiddle. That said, it's cleaner the way it is now.

Comment: Well, in you fiddle, you are executing your `if` statement right away but you are actually storing something in the storage when the user clicks a button. Therefore, at the time when you check localStorage, there isn't anything yet stored in it.

Comment: The idea is that on page load it runs the if statement, and if the conditions are met (because the localstorage has been previously set) it will hide the div with the offer in it.

Answer (score 0):

You use "timepid" in getItem, but you set the value in "timedpid", try this `localStorage.getItem('timedpid')`

Comment: While this is a valid point, questions about problems caused by a typo error should be closed, not answered. You don't have your close-vote hammer just yet, but keep it in mind for when you do: comment with the typo you spotted, and close-vote :)